# Node version v17.3.0, but environment set up for node 12.18.2. How change environment to 17.3.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I updated node to v17.3.0. When I type in `cmd` ----> `node -v`. I have version v17.3.0. I am trying to install `react-create-app` and can't. I have the message `Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 12.18.2 (x64) and npm.` How to solve  this problem?

Comment: It’s possible if you’re doing an install using sudo that your root user has v12 and your user has v17. 
Using nvm for both would be easier to manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest installing and using `nvm` - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Once you install it, you can do `nvm install 17.3.0` and then `nvm use 17.3.0`

This script makes it really easy to switch between node & npm versions.

Comment: I installed nvm. But when I try in icon I can't see any window.

Comment: @Umbro it's a command-line tool. Open up your terminal and type the commands I wrote above.

Comment: I have message: Node.js v17.13.0 is not yet released or available. when I used nvm install 17.13.0

Comment: @Umbro The latest version of Node is v17.3.0, so try using `nvm install 17.3.0 and nvm use 17.3.0`. You can see the list of available versions by doing `nvm ls-remote`

Comment: Please change in your post from 17.13.0 to 17.3.0

Comment: I installed using `nvm install 17.3.0`.But when I used `nvm use 17.3.0` I have message `access denid` and `unable to create a file that already exists`